# Unable to read custom http headers in javascript onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jersey-2.0

While i am trying to read custom http headers.i am hetting null.

Jersey authentication resource :-

```
   @Path("/redirect")
   public class RedirectDemo {
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType. APPLICATION_JSON )
   public Response getRedirect(@Context ServletContext context,UserTO user) {
   UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath(context.getContextPath());
   System. out .println("User name is:"+user.getUserName());
   System. out .println("Password is:"+user.getPassword());
   builder.path("/main.html");
   return Response
   .status(Response.Status. SEE_OTHER )
   .header(HttpHeaders. AUTHORIZATION ,"Response authorize")
   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,
   DELETE, PUT")
   .header("Access-Control-Expose-
   Headers",HttpHeaders. AUTHORIZATION )
   .header(HttpHeaders. LOCATION , builder.build())
   .build();
   }
  }
```

Login – page :-

```
   <! DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">  
   <title>Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container-test">
   <h3>
    <strong>iDNS</strong>
   </h3>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
   <form class="form-signin" id="loginForm" name="loginForm"
   action="/JerseyPageRedirection/redirect/redirect" method="post"
   id="login_form">
   <div class="errmsg text-center"></div>
   <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label> <input
   type="email"
   id="emailId" class="form-control" name="emailId"<label
    type="password"
    placeholder="Email address" required autofocus> <br>
   for="inputPassword">Password</label> <input
   id="password" class="form-control" name="password"
   placeholder="Password" required> <br>
   <!-- id="login-submit" -->
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
   onclick="doLogin()">Sign in</button>
   </form>
   </div>
   <script>
   function doLogin() {
   var userName = window
   .btoa(document.getElementById('emailId').value);
   var password = window
   .btoa(document.getElementById('password').value);
   var formData = JSON.stringify({
         userName : userName,
         password : password
     });
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("POST", "/JerseyPageRedirection/redirect/redirect");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     xhr.send(formData);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));//null
     window.location.href = xhr.responseURL;//Redirect works
     }
    }
    </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Headers :-

[image: Headers]

[image]

Issue :-

```
  I am unable read Authorization header content.
```

I want to read the header value only in javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to wait until the headers have been sent ... test for `xhr.readyState >= 2` ... I would also set the onreadystatechange function before xhr.send()

Comment: @Jaromanda X i tried your suggestion even though it does not work.

Comment: `i tried your suggestion` - what did you actually do with my vague suggestion? ... `it does not work` - any developer console errors?

Comment: no error on developer console.

Comment: checking xhr.readyState >= 3 .but it is not working

Comment: maybe because you're changing the current page ... comment out `window.location.href = xhr.responseURL;` and test again ... by the way, headers should be available once `xhr.readyState >= 2` (I original typed 3, but that was a typo on my part)

Comment: i am trying that also ,still i am getting same null value.

Comment: test for  `readyState == 4` then (perhaps different browsers have different states!)

Answer (score 2):

If someone still looking for the answer, you need to set "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" along side with the response. In example :

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,X-RateLimit-Limit,X-RateLimit-Remaining,X-RateLimit-Reset
```

Answer (score 0):

change your callback:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4){//if you are looking only for HTTP 200, then add condition xhr.status == 200
         console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));//will get your response header
         window.location.href = xhr.responseURL;//Redirect works
      }
  }
```

**Note:**
`readyState` Holds the status of the `XMLHttpRequest`. Changes from 0 to 4:

> 0: request not initialized
>
> 1: server connection established
>
> 2: request received
>
> 3: processing request
>
> 4: request finished and response is ready

Comment: where do those values for readyState come from? w3school? according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties) the values are: 0 = unset, 1 = opened (send called), 2 = headers received (headers and status available), 3 = receiving data (responseText will have partial content), 4 = done

Comment: i tried above code you mentioned .but still i am getting null.

Comment: @Murugesan Era Can you try getting some other header say `Content-Length`, to confirm problem is with only specific header.Try it by commenting `window.location.href`

Comment: @ Tom Sebastian i comment it and i am tried that time also i unable to read header content.

Comment: @ Murugesan Era oh . other headers also not woking?

Comment: @ Murugesan Era instead of console.log try alert() or debug the script.I copied your code and it is working for me

Comment: @Tom Sebastian what browser you are working .i tried with chrome,firefox in both it does not work.