# ajax xhr.getResponseHeader - missing custom header on http error response

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, http-headers

## Setup

- jquery 3.3.1
- nginx 1.13.8
- jetty/java backend

## Desired behaviour

When there is an error (40x or 50x http status) the backend should inform the client what exactly happened. A custom string is good enough for us and we would like to send it in the HTTP response as a custom header called **X-error**

## Ajax client request

CORS enabled

[image]

## The problem

There are no custom headers coming back in the response when 40x (404 in this particular case).

## nginx

[image]

## browser screenshots

### OPTIONS (preflight)

[image]

### GET

[image: get]

## The question

When there is a problem (http status 40x or 50x) X-error header is not coming back in jqXHR **even thought in the browser we can see it** as per screenshots. How do we do this? What setting is missing?

## Finally

[nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) we are using the 'always' setting so X-error is coming perfectly when http response is 20x but never when 40x. It's hard to conclude whether actually 40x responses are allowed to carry custom headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read custom http headers in javascript onreadystatechange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447224/unable-to-read-custom-http-headers-in-javascript-onreadystatechange)