# Cannot access headers of the error response

Tags: angular

In Angular 6, I am not able to get the headers of an http error response. For example, the server returns status code 401 but also includes extra headers in this error response. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
log(url:string){
    let res = this.http.get<any>(url,  httpOptions) as Observable<HttpResponse<any>>;
    res.subscribe(
        (data: any) => {console.log(data.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate'))}, // success path
        error =>{console.log(error.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate'))} // error path
     );
}

private getHttpOptions():any {

    const headers = {};
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + "123";

    const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders(headers), 
                         observe: "response"
                         };
    return httpOptions;
}
```

Comment: Can you share what headers are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: @HaseebAhmed I am trying to get the "WWW-Authenticate" header but enumerating the received header keys also results in an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer. Reading custom headers is disallowed by the browser due to security reasons. XmlHttpRequest is explicitly stating this as the error but apperently Angular prefers to silence this issue and simply returns null for the requested header key. The server needs to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header in order for the browser to allow code to access these headers. Detailed explanation can be found here : [Unable to read custom http headers in javascript onreadystatechange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447224/unable-to-read-custom-http-headers-in-javascript-onreadystatechange)